# Facebook Posts via 3rd Party Scheduler not visible to people

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am posting on my facebook page using 3rd Party Scheduler but I am guessing the post is not visible to people. I am not getting views on those posts or any interactions.

I am using Facebook C# SDK. Below is the snippet of the code, where 'file' is FacebookMediaStream object.

```
 var fb = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
 result = fb.Post(mapping.pageId + "/photos",
    new
    {
        message = 'Demo Title',
        file
    });
```

The post does appear on the page feed but I am guessing not on the people's newsfeed since there aren't any views for the posts.
Is there any change in EdgeRank algorithm or some parameter issue while posting it to FB?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me trying to use php sdk to post on a group feed. The issue was that the application was in development mode. You can check it in the app dashboard near the name of the app (a green circle).